# How to change wav bits per sample from 16 to 32 in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, wav

I want to change source wav file bits per sample from 16 to 32
To do this I update:

1. raw data: convert each 2 bytes to short, then cast to float then to bytes array (instead of initial two bytes)
2. data length field by doubling
3. bits per sample by doubling
4. byte rate field just by doubling
5. block align parameter by doubling

After saving wav file a lot of noise appears and sound becomes very loud.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you cast the short to a float and then to a byte array?

Comment: I don't think you can just modify the file in a raw format like this. Probably much easier to use an audio library like NAudio

Comment: Simplistic code will indeed introduce arifacts. You would have to make sure all rounding is either avoided (harder than one may expect) or dithered away (tedious).

Comment: Also, are you taking the endianness of the file into account?

Comment: @RonBeyer, because 16 bps means that each level stored in 16 bits, i should convert it to float (32 bits) and replace 2 short bytes to 4 float bytes

Comment: @TaW not sure I understand you correctly, but i just convert shorts to floats, and there cannot be any roundings. Or what do you mean?

Comment: float will always introduce rounding.

Comment: @Taw I still don't understand you) After converting to floats, new values will not have a decimal part, e.g. 84 will be converted to 84.0. Should I somehow modify this value?

Comment: thanks @DavidG, i'll look at this library